# rand() retornando o mesmo valor mesmo com a inclusão de srand((unsigned)time(NULL)

Tags: c, random

Por qual razão a função rolaDados abaixo retorna sempre os mesmos valores quando chamada múltiplas vezes, apesar da seed srand((unsigned)time(NULL)) ter sido inicializada?

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int rolaDados(int *a){
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;


    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
       temp += 1 + rand()%6;
    }
    return(temp);
}

void main(){
    int a=rolaDados(&a);
    int b=rolaDados(&b);
    int c=rolaDados(&c);

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d",a,b,c);
}
```

Exemplo de saida:

```
13
13
13
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

O seu erro é que você está lançando uma semente várias vezes, coloque srand na main e veja o resultado.

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int rolaDados(){
    int i = 0;
    int temp = 0;

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
       temp += 1 + rand() % 6;
    }

    return(temp);
}

void main(){
    srand(time(NULL));

    int a=rolaDados();
    int b=rolaDados();
    int c=rolaDados();

    printf("%d\n%d\n%d",a,b,c);
}
```